# Internal link in email?

Tags: email, hyperlink

How do I insert an internal link in an email?

Here's html I open in browser, copy-paste in gmail, send it to myself and expect its internal links to be working:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#Title1" title="Click to go to Title 1">Birds</a></p>
    <p><a href="#Title2" title="Click to go to Title 2">Trees</a></p>
    <p><a href="#Title3" title="Click to go to Title 3">Flowers</a></p>
    <h4 id="Title1">Birds</h4>
    <p> There are many different birds. There are... </p>
    <h4 id="Title2">Trees</h4>
    <p> Trees have many different colors and branches... </p>
    <h4 id="Title3">Flowers</h4>
    <p> The Lignum Vitae is the national flower of Jamaica... </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit**:

I'm sending the following to my self:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#Title1" title="Click to go to Title 1">Birds</a></p>
    <p><a href="#Title2" title="Click to go to Title 2">Trees</a></p>
    <p><a href="#Title3" title="Click to go to Title 3">Flowers</a></p>
    <h4 id="Title1"><a name="Title1">Birds</a></h4>
    <p> There are many different birds. There are... HOWEVER, it should be noted that Gmail appears to override the default browser/HTML functionality with JavaScript (and inserts a prefix into the named anchor and corresponding href so as not to interfere with its web interface). Consequently it seems that Gmail will only scroll to the named anchor if it is currently out of view - if it is already visible then no scroll occurs. HOWEVER, it should be noted that Gmail appears to override the default browser/HTML functionality with JavaScript (and inserts a prefix into the named anchor and corresponding href so as not to interfere with its web interface). Consequently it seems that Gmail will only scroll to the named anchor if it is currently out of view - if it is already visible then no scroll occurs.</p>
    <h4 id="Title2"><a name="Title2">Trees</a></h4>
    <p> Trees have many different colors and branches... HOWEVER, it should be noted that Gmail appears to override the default browser/HTML functionality with JavaScript (and inserts a prefix into the named anchor and corresponding href so as not to interfere with its web interface). Consequently it seems that Gmail will only scroll to the named anchor if it is currently out of view - if it is already visible then no scroll occurs. HOWEVER, it should be noted that Gmail appears to override the default browser/HTML functionality with JavaScript (and inserts a prefix into the named anchor and corresponding href so as not to interfere with its web interface). Consequently it seems that Gmail will only scroll to the named anchor if it is currently out of view - if it is already visible then no scroll occurs.</p>
    <h4 id="Title3"><a name="Title3">Flowers</a></h4>
    <p> The Lignum Vitae is the national flower of Jamaica... HOWEVER, it should be noted that Gmail appears to override the default browser/HTML functionality with JavaScript (and inserts a prefix into the named anchor and corresponding href so as not to interfere with its web interface). Consequently it seems that Gmail will only scroll to the named anchor if it is currently out of view - if it is already visible then no scroll occurs. HOWEVER, it should be noted that Gmail appears to override the default browser/HTML functionality with JavaScript (and inserts a prefix into the named anchor and corresponding href so as not to interfere with its web interface). Consequently it seems that Gmail will only scroll to the named anchor if it is currently out of view - if it is already visible then no scroll occurs.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and links aren't clickable. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *gmail* you will need to use named anchors:

```
<a name="Title1">Birds</a>
```

As you might expect, different email clients... work differently. Some support internal links to IDs; some don't; some support both. AFAIK gmail only supports *named* anchors. Bear in mind that there will likely be some email clients that won't support internal linking at all.

The `id` in the `h4` isn't strictly necessary since the named anchor should work in the majority of email clients. However, there is no reason not to have both as far as I can tell. The following works for me in Gmail:

```
<h4 id="Title1"><a name="Title1">Birds</a></h4>
```

HOWEVER, it should be noted that Gmail appears to override the default browser/HTML functionality with JavaScript (and inserts a prefix into the named anchor and corresponding href so as not to interfere with its web interface). Consequently it seems that **Gmail will only scroll to the named anchor if it is currently out of view** - if it is already visible then no scroll occurs.

Comment: Wait -- what then should be in `<h4>`? Can You give a complete example? Can't make it work.

Comment: You can keep the `h4` as it is as far as I can tell. I've updated my answer. Note that since Gmail only seems to scroll if the target is out of view, you might not see the scroll in your example, unless you make the viewport small or add more content. "copy-paste in gmail" - presumably you don't literally mean you copy-paste your HTML into Gmail?

Comment: Nope -- I open html in browser, and copy-paste that to gmail. I doesn't work. I've posted the full html I tried.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm a bit puzzled by what you mean... how do you "copy-paste that to gmail"? You can't simply copy/paste a chunk of HTML into an email you are composing in the Gmail web interface if that is what you are implying? (Gmail will escape it and display the raw HTML.) Although I assume that is not what you are doing since some of your HTML would appear to be interpreted correctly as you would otherwise be asking a different question. I have answered your question assuming you are generating an HTML email using a server-side script (eg. PHP).

Comment: Your 2nd code sample (exactly as written) works OK for me if I send this to a Gmail account. Bear in mind that if you are using another email client to send the email then it is possible that this is changing the structure of the message _before_ it is sent.

Comment: Incidentally, this also works for me in the Gmail app on Android.

Comment: It works if I send the html code using Thunderbird. Before that I opened the html in firefox, copied the content of the page and paste that into gmail compose window. This way it doesn't work. Thanks!