# Anchored links in Outlook(Mac) HTML mail not working

Tags: html, email, outlook

I have a problem with internal links in outlook for Mac  (Ver. 15.12.3).

This is the markup i am using:

```
<a href="#verseng" class="orange">english version below</a>
....
<span id="verseng"><a name="verseng">&nbsp;</a></span>
```

This is working fine in GMail or Roundcube, but not in outlook.

When i click the link i get the following error/message.

[image: error]

I found this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213698/internal-link-in-email), but including "name" did not help.
Did anyone succeed in using internal links?